# How do I switch off products display on Category pages

Tags: cs-cart

I am new to CS-cart and trying to set this up for my multi-vendor e-commerce shop.(and I am not a programmer)

So here's my problem, I don't want products to be displayed on any category pages.

This is the flow I am looking to have

Grid of main categories (on homepage)> List of sub category> Associated Sub category> and then products.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are on the latest release of Cs-cart (v.4.x.x), as you did not mention it.

You can control wether you want to show products from subcategories or not through the global setting option "Show products from subcategories of the selected category" that you'll find on the Settings/General menu of your admin area. See the screenshot:

[image]

I hope that helps you!

Comment: You are welcome! If my answer was helpful, please rate it. If it wasn't, accept my apologies, sincerely.